# Mobilefirst 8.0 cordova apps not able to connect server

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

POC for MobileFirst 8.0 version apps and I created sample apps and maven based adapter. Finally I invoked that adapter index.js file to call the adapter its working fine when I used browser simulator but its not working while I installed android device I got below that error in android LOGCAT,

[ERROR:xwalk_autofill_client.cc(121)] Not implemented reached in virtual void xwalk::XWalkAutofillClient::OnFirstUserGestureObserved()

How to resolve this issue.

please find the implementation below.

```
adapter
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
 Licensed Materials - Property of IBM
 5725-I43 (C) Copyright IBM Corp. 2011, 2013. All Rights Reserved.
 US Government Users Restricted Rights - Use, duplication or
 disclosure restricted by GSA ADP Schedule Contract with IBM Corp.
-->
<mfp:adapter name="HttpAdapter"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mfp="http://www.ibm.com/mfp/integration"
    xmlns:http="http://www.ibm.com/mfp/integration/http">

 <displayName>HttpAdapter</displayName>
 <description>HttpAdapter</description>
 <connectivity>
  <connectionPolicy xsi:type="http:HTTPConnectionPolicyType">
   <protocol>https</protocol>
   <domain>mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com</domain>
   <port>443</port>
   <connectionTimeoutInMilliseconds>30000</connectionTimeoutInMilliseconds>
   <socketTimeoutInMilliseconds>30000</socketTimeoutInMilliseconds>
   <maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode>50</maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode>
  </connectionPolicy>
 </connectivity>

 <procedure name="getFeed" secured="false"/>
 <procedure name="unprotected" secured="false"/>

</mfp:adapter>
adapter implementation
function getFeed(tag) {
 var input = {
     method : 'get',
     returnedContentType : 'xml',
     path : getPath(tag)
 };

 return MFP.Server.invokeHttp(input);
}

/**
 * Helper function to build the URL path.
 */
function getPath(tag){
    if(tag === undefined || tag === ''){
        return 'feed.xml';
    } else {
        return 'blog/atom/' + tag + '.xml';
    }
}

/**
 * @returns ok
 */
function unprotected(param) {
 return {result : "Hello from unprotected resource"};
}
apps implementation
function myFunction(){
 console.log('==================== inside calling ==================');
 var resourceRequest = new WLResourceRequest(
         "/adapters/HttpAdapter/getFeed",
         WLResourceRequest.GET,3000
     );

    resourceRequest.setQueryParameter("params", "['']");

    resourceRequest.send().then(
        function(response) {
         alert("------- success " +JSON.stringify(response));
        },
        function() {
         alert("----------- >>> errror ------");
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: Provide your implementation... you provided nothing.

Comment: Why do you put this in comments? Delete these comments and click the EDIT button in your question.

Comment: You also mention "xwalk". Did you install something that you did not mention in the question? Mention EVERYTHING.

Answer (score 0):

Please use mata tag in your HTML file it will resolve your issues for android.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' http://* 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' http://* 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'" />
```